# Как настроить 3proxy на сервере?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, vpn

Есть сервер. Нужно на нем поднять 3proxy или любой другой подобный прокси-сервер

На сервере есть два ip адреса:
222.222.222.222
и 192.168.10.10 (это адрес, который сервер получает путем туннелирования). Этот адрес белый и выходит в интернет с адресом 111.111.111.111

Я поднял 3proxy и у меня получилось настроить все с адресом internal222.222.222.222  external 222.222.222.222

А как настроить 192.168.10.10, что бы я мог к нему подключится из вне и использовать как прокси? (типа сделать из туннеля еще 1 туннель (или прокси))

Answer (score 1):

Можно не указывать директивы **internal** и **external**, а при описании прокси указать их отдельно.

```
auth iponly  
deny * * 
allow * 192.168.10.0/24 * * * #разрешаем подключаться только из этой сети.
proxy -a -i 192.168.10.10 -e 222.222.222.222 -p 8080 #i -входящий адрес, e - исходящий адрес, p - порт.
flush

auth iponly  
deny * * 
allow * * * * * #разрешаем подключаться всем к этому прокси. 
proxy -a -i 222.222.222.222 -e 222.222.222.222
```

Так же можно и не указывать -i, тогда listen будет на всех интерфейсах.

Но прокси должен видеть физически эти интерфейсы, т.е. в конфиге нельзя указать удалённый адрес 111.111.111.111

Я бы на Вашем месте сделал бы каскадный прокси. Т.е. на удалённой машине поднял бы тоже 3proxy, а в этом указал родительский прокси. Например:

```
allow * 
parent 1000 http 111.111.111.111 3128
proxy -p8080
```

Comment: на удаленном сервере поднят vpn, 3proxy поднять нету возможности. А можно указать как то так: -i111.111.111.111 -e192.168.5.5 (адрес интерфейса на котором стоит vpn туннель). По идее, трафик пойдет на 192.168.5.5, а с него уже на внешний адрес vpn-сервера 123.123.123.123